# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2

Tags: java

I am getting this exception on below code

```
nIndex=nIndex + strWord.length();
nIndex = strHindiTextInUpperCase.indexOf(strWord, nIndex);
character=strHindiTextInUpperCase.charAt(nIndex-1);
```

I am getting an exception on this code as `String index out of range: -2`
on line  character=strHindiTextInUpperCase.charAt(nIndex-1);

this code is also new for me.so please help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: You match your data inside the string and as per that you count and operate for string methods.Your mistake is your string has less data , but you are accessing extra index.

Comment: Which of the three lines gives this error? What is  the value of `strHindiTextInUpperCase`?  Waht is the value of `strWord`?

Comment: character=strHindiTextInUpperCase.charAt(nIndex-1);
what it means??
Can any one explain me.

Answer (score 7):

If it doesn't find `strWord`, `strHindiTextInUpperCase.indexOf(strWord, nIndex);` returns -1.

Then `strHindiTextInUpperCase.charAt(nIndex-1);` will look at index -2.

Answer (score -1):

Index out of range is because U try to access the character which is outside the range of the string . Please check the string length and try to access in the range 0>=range<(strlen-1)